# How to fix : Cannot convert lambda expression to type int because is not delegate?

Tags: c#

i am trying to get user decision from the list but i get that  Cannot convert lambda expression to type int because is not delegate. How can i solve this? I have had a look on the internet but since i am quite new i am not sure what is the right solution

```
public static List<int> UserDecisionResult  { get; set; }

public void GetUserDecision()
        {
            List<int> userDecision = new List<int>();
            if (FilterAllItems) userDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = -1);
            if (FilterBeginnerItems) userDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 1);
            if (FilterIntermediateItems) userDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 2);
            if (FilterUpperIntermediateItems) userDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 3);
            if (FilterAdvancedItems) userDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 4);
            UserDecisionResult = userDecision;


        }


        private static List<Article> FindAllArticlesForPurchase(List<Article> allArticles)
        {
            var result = UserDecisionResult;

            if (_parentCategoryId != -1)
            {
                foreach (var categoryGroup in _allUserCategoryGroups)
                {
                    var allGroupCategories = _allCategories.Where(m => m.CategoryGroupId == categoryGroup.Id).ToList();

                    if (_parentCategoryId != -1)
                    {
                        foreach (var category in allGroupCategories)
                        {
                            if (category.ParentId == _parentCategoryId && _parentCategoryId != -1)
                            {

                                var categoryArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase.Where(result.Contains(m => m.CategoryId == category.Id).ToList();
                                //var categoryArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase.Where(result.Contains(m => m.CategoryId == category.Id).ToList());
                                allArticles.AddRange(categoryArticles);
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase;
            }

            return allArticles;
        }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Could you point the exact line where the error arises ?

Comment: Thank you, here   var categoryArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase.Where(result.Contains(m => m.CategoryId == category.Id).ToList();

Comment: Aren't you missing a ending parentheses? `Where(result.Contains(m => m.CategoryId == category.Id))`

Comment: yes, i corrected that

Comment: It needs to be something like this: `var categoryArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase.Where(XXXX => result.Contains(m => m.CategoryId == category.Id).ToList();`. But where would you use `XXXX` on the RHS of `=>`?

Comment: Enigmativity I dont think that i really get you answer what should xxx be?

Comment: @Nodessa the `Contains` method definition looks like what ?

Comment: @Nodessa - use the `@` notation for notifications.

Comment: @Nodessa - The `XXXX` is what you're missing in your code. You must use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda expression is wrong here due to syntax. You can try:

```
var categoryArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase
                       .Where(m => m.CategoryId == category.Id 
                              && result.Contains(m.CategoryId))
                       .ToList();
```

or if `Contains` here is some custom implementation then try :

```
var categoryArticles = _allArticlesForPurchase
                   .Where(_ => result.Contains(m => _.CategoryId == category.Id))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: the second option didnt work for me, but the first yes